# Can ARKit classes be used on a macOS CLI project?

Tags: ios, macos, arkit

I have been working with ARKit 3 (the beta with Xcode beta as well). I understand that the ARKit framework is meant to be used on iOS devices, but what I'm wondering is if I can instantiate any of these classes in a macOS project?

I've archived an ARWorldMap object (from ARKit) on an iOS device and have downloaded the app bundle to inspect it on my MacBook.

I am trying to use NSKeyedUnarchiver to unarchive the data that was archived by NSKeyedArchiver and when I try to import ARKit in the MacBook project, I get the error below.

I understand that certain features shouldn't be expected to work outside of iOS devices, but can I not use the classes that hold specific data when I develop in Xcode for programs targeting a MacBook?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the error:

"No such module 'ARKit' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ARKit API is only available on iOS 11 and above.  At the time of this post.  The API relies on hardware features only available on an iPad or iPhone.

You can see Apple's API support in their documentation.  See `SDK` on the right side of their doc.  Here's a [link to Apple's ARKit API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit).

Comment: I am tempted to accept your answer, but I just wanted to confirm before clicking "accept": 

Are you aware of any work-around where I can use iOS SDK classes on macOS (ones that are generally holding data, and not touching hardware resources in their implementation) ? If not it would seem my only option is to serialize or store the information from the ARWorldMap myself, and de-serialize it into my own object?

Comment: iOS specific classes/APIs won't work on MacOS.  If you're wanting to persist data from ARKit to be used in MacOS, there are tutorials out there that can point you in the right direction.  Here's one of them: https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-persistence/

Comment: I should point out for others who may have the same question, that I've already consulted that article Derek posted. 

That use case is serializing an ARWorldMap instance to the Data type, and then using NSKeyedArchiver to write it into a binary plist format. The de-serialization back into an ARWorldMap occurs on the same device (or at least it applies to iOS devices only). 

If I cannot instantiate an ARWorldMap on macOS, then it seems I am going to have to pull out the fields/properties I want and serialize/de-serialize them as a custom object.

Comment: Looks like you don't have any other option other than serializing as your custom object for MacOS.  If you need to display anything visually on MacOS, might consider looking into Unity.  I don't have much experience with Unity, but it does have some ARKit support.  Best of luck!